# views placed below recyclerview are not showing

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

This is my xml layout. It is not displaying the views that are placed below recyclerview while running the app. I dont know why. None of the solutions I have found online have solved my issue. Will layout_weight or layout_below solve the problem?

Somewhere I found that:
*If your recycleview content will extend beyond the display height then you should consider dividing your layout into partitions with android:layout_weight.*

Can anyone please help me:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/viewBg"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home_screen">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/section_home_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search_btn"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/search_btn"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/search_layout"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Search here"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#999999"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/search_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search_field"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/search_field"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/search_button"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/section_home_recentsearchlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/section_home_search"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:text="Recently searched gyms"
                android:textColor="@color/light_black"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_gymsrecent_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/section_home_recentsearchlist"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/section_home_offers"
            android:layout_below="@id/section_home_recentsearchlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:text="Latest Offers"
                android:textColor="@color/light_black"
                android:textSize="14dp"/>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="175dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="#4169E1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="20dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Fitness Plus"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="23dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:text="Choice of Gym Trial Classes and More at Rs.149 only !\nEarn Upto 8.5% Cashback"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="14dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/darkorange"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:text=" Learn More "
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="175dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="#4169E1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="20dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Health Total"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="23dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:text="1-Month Health Plan for Lifestyle Ailments. "
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="14dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/darkorange"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:text=" Learn More "
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="175dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="#4169E1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="20dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Gym 'N' Swim"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="23dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:text="Swimming Pool &amp; Gym Memberships at Rs.5000 only. "
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="14dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/darkorange"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:text=" Learn More "
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/section_home_trainerfb"
            android:layout_below="@id/section_home_offers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:text="Trainer's Feedback"
                android:textColor="@color/light_black"
                android:textSize="14dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First remove this                 `android:layout_below="@id/section_home_recentsearchlist"` for `RecyclerView`. Also change this             `android:layout_below="@id/section_home_recentsearchlist"` to             `android:layout_below="@+id/section_home_recentsearchlist"` for `section_home_offers` linearlayout.

Comment: I'd recommend learning how to use `ConstraintLayout`. It's much better than nesting View Groups. Also, you might want to put the views in a `NestedScrollView`. That way, when your `RecyclerView` expands due to `wrap_content`, you have a way to scroll to the bottom and see the views below it.

Comment: Yeah you can use weight if its a fixed like half or quater or so and so if not i suggest use the whole layout in a scroll view

Answer (score 0):

set fix height of the recycleview or set parent layout as linearlayout and set weight of all layouts like this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_gymsrecent_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/section_home_recentsearchlist"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

or

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_gymsrecent_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/section_home_recentsearchlist"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_weight` properly. try with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/section_home_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_field"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Search here"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/section_home_recentsearchlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:text="Recently searched gyms"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_gymsrecent_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/section_home_offers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:text="Latest Offers"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#4169E1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Fitness Plus"
                        android:textSize="23dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:text="Choice of Gym Trial Classes and More at Rs.149 only !\nEarn Upto 8.5% Cashback"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text=" Learn More "
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#4169E1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Health Total"
                        android:textSize="23dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:text="1-Month Health Plan for Lifestyle Ailments. "
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text=" Learn More "
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#4169E1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Gym 'N' Swim"
                        android:textSize="23dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:text="Swimming Pool &amp; Gym Memberships at Rs.5000 only. "
                        android:textSize="14dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text=" Learn More "
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/section_home_trainerfb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="Trainer's Feedback"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'trainerfb' align to parent bottom, 'home_offers' above 'trainerfb' and 'recentsearchlist' fill up all the space in the middle of the display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/viewBg"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home_screen">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/section_home_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search_btn"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/search_btn"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/search_layout"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/search_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/section_home_recentsearchlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_home_search"
    android:layout_above="@id/section_home_offers"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Recently searched gyms"
        android:textColor="@color/light_black"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_gymsrecent_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/section_home_recentsearchlist"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/section_home_offers"
    android:layout_above="@id/section_home_trainerfb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Latest Offers"
        android:textColor="@color/light_black"
        android:textSize="14dp"/>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#4169E1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Fitness Plus"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="23dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="Choice of Gym Trial Classes and More at Rs.149 only !\nEarn Upto 8.5% Cashback"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/darkorange"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text=" Learn More "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#4169E1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Health Total"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="23dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="1-Month Health Plan for Lifestyle Ailments. "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/darkorange"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text=" Learn More "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#4169E1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Gym 'N' Swim"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="23dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="Swimming Pool &amp; Gym Memberships at Rs.5000 only. "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/darkorange"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text=" Learn More "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/section_home_trainerfb"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Trainer's Feedback"
        android:textColor="@color/light_black"
        android:textSize="14dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```